# Is the Sabbath a Creation Ordinance?

Tags: shabbat, gentiles, creation

"And on the seventh day God finished His work which He had made; and He rested on the seventh day from all His work which He had made." Genesis 2:2

Some understand that this verse teaches that Shabbat was instituted at creation, and is therefore a universal moral requirement (for all people, and all time). It follows from this assumption that Shabbat would have been observed by Adam, Enoch and Noah.

Please comment on the accuracy of this, or point me to a Jewish scholarly work that would be able to set this issue straight.

Comment: "Some understand..." Who have you heard this explanation from?

Comment: I heard it from a non-Jewish source. I am just wondering whether there are any Jewish resources which might explain what was meant by God "resting" on the seventh day, at the end of creation week, if it is not a Sabbath institution. I am hoping that makes sense. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: wouldn't Exodus 31:16-17 invalidate that understanding by explicitly saying that the Sabbath and its observance are a covenant between God and the Jewish people? Gen 2:2 doesn't say that anything related to the sabbath is a requirement of man.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) .

Comment: See the second answer to this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13447/is-it-a-discouraged-or-an-unacceptable-practice-for-a-gentile-to-keep-the-sabbat/13470#13470