# Can a Noachide believing they are obligated make themselves obligated?

Tags: noachide-laws

I am a Noachide, who came out of so-called "Messianic Judaism" after about 20 years. During those years, I believed I was part of Israel and the mitzvot were incumbent on me. I gave up jobs, sought a wife of like mind, and began to raise my children that way.

Now, I "understand" that's not true. But it is hard to tell myself that since I conducted myself as if obligated (though incorrectly) that HaShem wouldn't somehow treat it as such. I wanted to be obligated and I obeyed even when it cost me. Does that confer some obligation?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Jesse and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Numbers.30.6.2

Answer (score 1):

Wanting to be obligated or believing oneself to be obligated in following the mitzvot is not sufficient to incur an actual obligation beyond the [Seven Noahide Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Laws_of_Noah), which are obligatory for all people. The Torah is a special covenant (often described in terms of a marriage) between God and the Jewish people and non-Jews are not included in that exclusive relationship.

A strong yearning to join the Jewish people and become obligated in the commandments can be the spark of motivation to convert to Judaism and join the relationship between Israel and God; however, absent a formal conversion, someone who is not Jewish is not obligated to follow the laws (and is even [forbidden](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13448/1713) to follow some of them).

Comment: thank you. That's what I expected. In Judaism, clear thinking seems to trump feelings. As it should.

Comment: @JesseClark welcome to Mi Yodeya Jesse. Just a comment: You still get credit for all the extra good things you did, even if you did them under a false idea that they were obligatory.

Comment: @DavidKenner What does "credit" mean?